# curl https SITE with proxy

Tags: php, curl, https, proxy

I want to curl https SITE with proxy, but I failed.

```
curl -x IP:PROT 'https://SITE'
```

It returns:

```
curl: (56) Proxy CONNECT aborted
```

Is there anyway that meet my need?
THX

P.S: I am using PHP (curl) also, and I want to do this with PHP.

HERE is my code:

```
$ip = "IP:PORT";
$url = "https://SITE";
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $ip);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($output);
```

Comment: AND "-k" doesn't work.

Comment: see CURLOPT_PROXYAUTH , CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE

Comment: thx, but I read the php manual, and those options doesn't help.....